# CSS - Placeholder padding in Chrome

Tags: html, css, forms, google-chrome

I want to style my form. I have active placeholder, in Firefox it's looking good:
[image]

but in Chrome is a problem:  (not with textarea, here is SS from old version, he is good, only with normal input is problem)
[image]

Here is my CSS:

```
.form-control::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: 200;
    font-size: 30px;
    color: #373737;
}

.form-control:-moz-placeholder {
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: 200;
    font-size: 30px;
    color: #373737;
}

.form-control::-moz-placeholder {
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: 200;
    font-size: 30px;
    color: #373737;
}

.form-control:-ms-input-placeholder {
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: 200;
    font-size: 30px;
    color: #373737;
}

textarea {
    height: 370px;
    padding: 20px !important;
}

input.form-control {
    height: 63px;
}

.form-control {
    color: #373737;
    background: #dbdbdb;
    border: 0;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

Comment: With the code you are attaching I can't reproduce the problem, however it sounds to me a problem with hardcoding the height. See the answer below or if this doesn't solve the problem , please, add a working example (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve )

Comment: Ok, here is https://jsfiddle.net/qf8L29u5/1/ code (only this form) @MarcosPérezGude

Comment: Thank you, I edit my answer. It works now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are hard-coding the height of the inputs here:

```
input.form-control {
    height: 63px;
}
```

Maybe you need to remove this and control with paddings or else play with `box-sizing` if you have another inherit padding

```
input.form-control {
    height: 63px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

### Edit:

It seems a bootstrap overriding, so inputs gets `height: 34px` from the `.form-control` selector (not your code, the bootstrap code). You need to avoid that with this changes:

https://jsfiddle.net/qf8L29u5/2/

Remove this:

```
#Contact input.form-control {
    height: 63px;
}
```

And add this:

```
#Contact .form-control {
    font-size: 30px;
    height: inherit;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but did not help

Comment: Then provide a working example. Read this carefully: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . But read it! A lot of people that I suggest to read MCVE help ignores me. Then they go crazy when its posts are deleted.